# Mysql get where not in with a twist

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, having-clause

I want to get the firms that dont have contact method main_phone or phone This is my schema

```
Firms table
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Firm1 |
|  2 | Firm2 |
|  3 | Firm3 |
+----+-------+

Contacts
+----+----------+---------+
| id |  label   | firm_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | Contact1 |       1 |
|  2 | Contact2 |       1 |
|  3 | Contact3 |       2 |
|  4 | Contact4 |       3 |
+----+----------+---------+

contact_methods
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | method_type | contact_id |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | main_phone  |          1 |
|  2 | main_fax    |          1 |
|  3 | email       |          1 |
|  4 | main_fax    |          4 |
|  5 | main_fax    |          3 |
|  6 | phone       |          2 |
|  7 | main_mobile |          1 |
|  8 | url         |          4 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

and this is my query

```
SELECT 
firms.id
FROM firms 
JOIN contacts ON (contactable_id = firms.id)
JOIN contact_methods ON contacts.id = contact_methods.contact_id
WHERE 
firms.active = 1
AND
contact_methods.method_type NOT IN ('mobile','phone','main_mobile','main_phone')
```

I am getting all firms :s

Comment: *I am getting all firms* Firm1 has main_fax and email via Contact1. Firm2 has main_fax via Contact3. Firm3 has main_fax and url via Contact4. PS. `firms.active` column not exists.

Comment: Show desired output for shown source data.

Comment: just delete it (WHERE firms.active = 1)

Comment: i want just the firms.id that does not have a contact method in ('mobile','phone','main_mobile','main_phone')

Comment: No such rows in shown sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks whether each firm has *any* contact type that does not belong to the list - while you want to ensure that *none* of the firm contact does.

One option uses aggregation:

```
select f.*
from firm f
left join contacts c on c.firm_id = f.id
left join contact_methods cm on cm.contact_id = c.id
group by f.id
having not max(cm.method_type in ('mobile','phone','main_mobile','main_phone')) <=> 1
```

Alternatively, you can use `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from firm f
where not exists (
    select 1
    from contacts c
    inner join contact_methods cm on cm.contact_id = c.id
    where c.firm_id = f.id and cm.method_type in ('mobile','phone','main_mobile','main_phone')
)
```

Comment: Seems good but its taking too much time :s didnt even get the result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM firms
WHERE NOT EXIST ( SELECT NULL
                  FROM contacts
                  WHERE firms.id = contacts.firm_id )
```

`contact_methods` not needed in this task.

If you need the same for definite contacts types then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM firms
WHERE NOT EXIST ( SELECT NULL
                  FROM contacts
                  JOIN contact_methods ON contacts.id = contact_methods.contact_id 
                  WHERE firms.id = contacts.firm_id
                    AND contact_methods.method_type NOT IN ({types list}) )
```

---

> i want just the firms.id that does not have a contact method in ('mobile','phone','main_mobile','main_phone')

```
SELECT *
FROM firms
WHERE NOT EXIST ( SELECT NULL
                  FROM contacts
                  JOIN contact_methods ON contacts.id = contact_methods.contact_id 
                  WHERE firms.id = contacts.firm_id
                    AND contact_methods.method_type IN ('mobile', 'phone', 'main_mobile', 'main_phone') )
```

Comment: @OthmaneBouhenna Updated according to the last comment to the question.